# How do I dolly or zoom using React three fiber or threejs?

Tags: three.js, orbitcontrols

I have a `react-three-fiber` app and I'm using `OrbitControls` as my camera controls.

I want to use buttons on screen to manually **zoom in/zoom out** but I can't get my code to work.

I want these buttons to work the same way as how the middle mouse button works with `OrbitControls`.
Does anyone how to make this work using `React`?

I tried changing the camera position using the `useThree()` hook but it was not working as I wanted.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the middle scroll wheel with `OrbitControls`, all it's doing is multiplying the camera position by a certain value. So, if you wanted to do this *manually*, then you could use the following function:

```js
function zoom(constant){
    camera.position.x = camera.position.x * constant;
    camera.position.y = camera.position.y * constant;
    camera.position.z = camera.position.z * constant;
}
```

If you want to **zoom in**, closer, then you pass a value **less than one** value. If you want to **zoom out**, further, you pass a value **greater than one** value.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried your solution and the zoom works just like OrbitControls. But I realized that OrbitControls doesn't let you zoom in infinitely. Is there any way to achieve that. For reference you can check FirstPersonControls. You can zoom infinitely using this control.

Comment: OrbitControls *does* let you zoom in infinitely. If you get too close the the target (0, 0, 0 by default), though, then it starts to slow down, because you can't zoom in further than the center. It just doesn't make sense. You can zoom *out* infinitely, because there is nothing stopping you there (no origin point). I hope that makes sense

Comment: Also, it would be great if you could upvote, it helps a lot :)

Comment: Sorry I was not clear with my question. What I meant was if I can keep moving forward even if I reach the center. If you take a look at this example https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_terrain . The camera is still able to move forward even if you reach the target. Is there a way to do this with OrbitControls

Comment: Ah, I understand. You could keep changing the target of the OrbitControls. You could use `controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 10, 0);`, and then use `controls.update()`

Comment: Can you please help me yet with another problem I'm facing right now? The zoom seems to be working fine as long as the target is (0,0,0) but when I pan the camera position and then zoom in using the buttons, the camera starts rotating weirdly around the target. Here is a simplified version I made on code sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/zoomtest-orbitcontrols-wwbmj3

Comment: Please repost this as another question, sorry for the late reply!